# output data type for mapply vs rbind in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a function call WOE, that return a data fame with 1 row, and 7 columns:

```
WOE(inData, splitCol, range, tgtCol, adjfac)
```

Where inData is a data frame, splitCol, tgtCol and adjfac are numeric, range can be a single number or a 2x1 matrix, 
e.g. range = 10 or range = c(10, 20)

Now I would like to write a function that when the range is a n-row matrix, then the function will do WOE row by row and return a data frame that have n row and 7 columns.
For now i am using a for loop with cbind:

```
df <- rbind(df, WOE(inData, splitCol, range[i,], tgtCol, adjfac))
for (i in 2:nrow(range)) {
  df <- rbind(df, WOE(inData, splitCol, range[i,], tgtCol, adjfac))
}
```

But I don't like for-loop... I want to make it simpler.
So I also have tried to use mapply like this:

```
 mapply(t(WOR, list(inData), list(splitCol), split(range, nrow(range)), list(tgtCol), list(adjfac))
```

but the above line doesn't return a data frame as I want, it return a data frame of a lot of lists, which is very difficult for me to do further calculation.

Does anyone have suggestions for me to aggregate my for-loop into less lines?
Thanks!

Comment: This will be much cleared if we actually could reproduce `WOE` and you included the output is a data.frame of a lot of lists a list of data.frames or a data.frame of lists? Also, why are you including `t(..)` in your call to `mapply` this would appear to be a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(range), function(i) WOE(inData, splitCol, range[i,], tgtCol, adjfac)))
```

I often use this idiom when I want precise control over how results from an "apply" operation are combined. This way I don't have to remember what the rules for automatic simplification are (i.e. sapply or mapply with simplify=TRUE).

Answer (score 0):

First suppose this:

```
WOE = function(i) data.frame(matrix(runif(7),nrow=1))
WOE(1)
#       X1     X2     X3     X4     X5      X6     X7
# 1 0.7973 0.5489 0.8095 0.6375 0.7322 0.03601 0.3647

sapply(seq(5), function(x) WOE(x))
#    [,1]   [,2]    [,3]     [,4]    [,5]   
# X1 0.6664 0.02439 0.8753   0.0384  0.5619 
# X2 0.7818 0.1433  0.005552 0.5223  0.3665 
# X3 0.6308 0.551   0.7413   0.6464  0.3405 
# X4 0.4988 0.04422 0.8696   0.9513  0.01265
# X5 0.92   0.9563  0.4194   0.03145 0.05684
# X6 0.4526 0.07379 0.246    0.6304  0.3623 
# X7 0.6959 0.087   0.99     0.8185  0.2488
```

Simple? So if according to @mnel comment below, matrix also suits you, you may act like this:

```
sapply(seq(2,nrow(range)), function(i) WOE(inData, splitCol, range[i,], tgtCol, adjfac))
```

But if you need strictly `data.frame` (all of the cells are not the same type) you may use this:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(2,nrow(range)), 
        function(i) WOE(inData, splitCol, range[i,], tgtCol, adjfac)))
```

Comment: The result is a matrix. Is this what the OP wants (this is rather unclear). data.frame to matrix conversion will only work nicely if all columns are numeric (or a single type)

Comment: Thank you! I do need a data frame